# Hashing a tuple not matching the expected value in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve the below problem:

Given an integer, n , and n space-separated integers as input, create a tuple, t , of those n integers. Then compute and print the result of hash(t).

I am using python 3.
My code is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    integer_list = map(int, input().split())
    t = tuple(integer_list)
    print(hash(t))
```

The expected output is ***3713081631934410656*** but I am getting ***-3550055125485641917***. I think my code is correct. Why am i getting a different output?

If I am using Pypy3, I am getting the correct output ***3713081631934410656*** but not with Python 3

Comment: print out `integer_list` and `t` to confirm your code actually does what you intended

Comment: Yes, I tried that. In fact the first thing I did was to ensure that the ```integer_list``` and ```t``` are right. The values are correct.
When I give 2 and 1 2,
the ```integer_list``` is which is a map object, after converting to list the value is ```[1,2]```
the ```t``` which is a tuple, prints ```(1,2)```

I also tried printing ```hash((1,2))``` and it prints  ***-3550055125485641917***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't promise that tuple hashing will produce any particular output. There is no such thing as the "correct" output for `hash(some_tuple)`. The tuple hash implementation is free to change, and [it *has* changed](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/78932) in Python 3.8.

Your assignment was likely written for a different Python version than the one you're testing on, without consideration of the fact that the tuple hash algorithm is an implementation detail.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, so it was necessary to first make the list and then convert it to a tuple only at the time of printing.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    t = map(int, input().split())
    print(hash(tuple(t)))
```

Comment: `t` isn't a list in the first place (unless you are using Python 2), but an instance of the *type* `map` which `tuple` iterates over to create the tuple you hash.

Comment: (The only difference between your code and the code in the original question is that you passed the resulting tuple directly to `hash`, rather than assigning it to a name first.)

Comment: The submission does not answer the OP question